# PostGres - Insert list of tuples using execute instead of executemany

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am inserting thousands of rows, timing and speed is very important. I have found through benchmarking that postgres can ingest my rows faster using `execute()` instead of `executemany()`

This works well for me:

```
...

def insert(self, table, columns, values):
    conn = self.connectionPool.getconn()
    conn.autocommit = True

    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            query = (
                 f'INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) '
                 f'VALUES {values} '
                 f'ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;'
             ).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')  # Notice the replace x2 to get rid of the list brackets

            print(query)
            cursor.execute(query)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        self.connectionPool.putconn(conn)

...

self.insert('types', 'name, created_at', rows)
```

After the double `replace`, printing `query` returns something like this and the rows are ingested:

```
INSERT INTO types (name, created_at) VALUES ('TIMER', '2022-04-09 03:19:49'), ('Sequence1', '2022-04-09 03:19:49') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Is my approach secure? Is there a more pythonic implementation using `execute`?

Comment: Relevant https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers

Comment: And [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for dynamic SQL. Your method has SQL injection written all over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn’t secure or even reliable – Python `repr` isn’t compatible with PostgreSQL string syntax (try some strings with single quotes, newlines, or backslashes).

- Consider passing array parameters instead and using [`UNNEST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-array.html#:%7E:text=unnest%20(%20anyarray%2C%20anyarray%20%5B%2C%20...%20%5D%20)%20%E2%86%92%20setof%20anyelement%2C%20anyelement%20%5B%2C%20...%20%5D):

  ```
  cursor.execute(
      "INSERT INTO types (name, created_at)"
      " SELECT name, created_at FROM UNNEST (%(names)s, %(created_ats)s) AS t",
      {
          'names': ['TIMER', 'Sequence1', ...],
          'created_ats': ['2022-04-09 03:19:49', ...],
      })
  ```

  This is the best solution, as the query doesn’t depend on the parameters (can be prepared and cached, statistics can be easily grouped, makes the absence of SQL injection vulnerability obvious, can easily log queries without data).
- Failing that, build a query that’s only dynamic in the number of parameters, like `VALUES ((%s, %s, ...), (%s, %s, ...), ...)`. Note that PostgreSQL has a parameter limit, so you might need to produce these in batches.
- Failing that, use [`psycopg2.sql.Literal`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Literal).

Comment: Thank you - how can the method in bullet point 1 be adapted for use with an `upsert`? I.e., `ON CONFLICT (name) DO UPDATE SET updated_at = EXCLUDED.created_at`

Comment: @Ajility: It should work the same, as long as you put the `ON CONFLICT` in the syntactically correct place (at the end, here).